# Browser network trace showing JSON post creating same file/link for every posting JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using Json post method to get data from controller and display the data on Razor view page using dropdown list. When I am tracing browser network tab, I can see it is creating and keeping every post request and increasing the file size. I am new for JQuery. My question is, there are any way I can remove the previous post. Please see the image file below where I posted twice from dropdown list. I always want to keep the last post.

[Please click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4oMk.png)

My JQuery code is -

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#ddl2').change(function (e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();          
            var data1 = {str_test: str_test }; 
            var url = '@Url.Action("ddl_2")?id=' + id;    
            $.post(url, data1, function (data)
            {
                $('#nav_div').html(data);
            });

        });
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "file"? I see two browser requests that do not create  files.

Comment: @Phil, I you look the link, it is same link in the file section

Answer (score 0):

Either you're posting multiple time or you've called the same function with same selector each time. You could post your JS logic code here to debug correctly otherwise assumption answer aren't helpful.

Comment: Please see my edited question, I have added the jquery code

Comment: Try this  and let me know. 

`$('#ddl2').on("change", function(e){
     var $myDiv =  $('#nav_div');
     e.preventDefault();  
      $.ajax({
          method:"post",
          url: url,
         data: data1,
        success: function(res){
           $myDiv.html(res);
         },
        error: function(res){
          cosole.log(res);
        }
      });
});`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is working the same way as mine, this is also creating link for every change event

Comment: Then i guess you're calling or referencing the function for change event multiple time. You could debug the line in browser debugger tab or Please test the process in another file then implement it to your project.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked, but did not find I am calling or referencing multiple times, I will follow your advice now to implement in another file and browser debugger